# Fluentd S3 logs

Tags: amazon-s3, fluentd

Trying to push logs from local application to S3 bucket , using fluentd , but the files are created based on index, is it possible to accumulated towards one single file? Any suggestion?

Logs are pushed to S3 bucket but not in single files